# Detect if touching body LibGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm trying to see if a touch position collides with a Body and I'm not sure about the best way to implement it.

As of now, I have an Obstacle.java that draws a polygon-shaped body as a rectangle. It works fine to draw in the world, I just need to check for collisions.

Furthermore, I want to add some Sprite/Texture/Image to this body, so maybe it's better to check for collision between the sprite rather than the body, I'm not sure. So any pointers in the right direction would be helpful.

**Obstacle.java**

```
public class Obstacle{
    public int x,y;
    public Vector3 position;
    public World world;

    private Body body;
    private BodyDef bodyDef;
    private PolygonShape shape;

    private float density = 1f;
    private final float width = 360f;
    private final float height = 20f;

    Random r;

    public Obstacle(World world) {
        r = new Random();

        this.world = world;

        //rectangle
        bodyDef = new BodyDef();
        bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
        bodyDef.position.set( new Vector2( x + width / 2, y + height / 2));

        float randomValue = (float)(0 + (540 - 0) * r.nextDouble());

        shape = new PolygonShape();
        shape.setAsBox( width / 2, height / 2 );

        body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
        body.createFixture(shape, density);
        body.setTransform(randomValue,1160,0);

        float angularVelocity;
        if(r.nextInt(2)==0){
            angularVelocity=-3;
        }else{
            angularVelocity=3;
        }

        body.setAngularVelocity(angularVelocity);
        body.setLinearVelocity(0,-250);

    }

    public float getX() {
        return position.x;
    }
    public float getY() {
        return position.y;
    }

    public float getWidth() {
        return 360 / GdxGame.PPM;
    }

    public float getHeight() {
        return 20 / GdxGame.PPM;
    }

    public void render(SpriteBatch batch,float delta) {
    }

    public Boolean collidesWithPlayer(float touchX, float touchY){
        return false;
    }

}
```

The last method **collidesWithPlayer** was an effort from me to implement the detection, and in my Screen.java I have:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < obstacles.size(); i++) {
     if(obstacles.get(i).collidesWithPlayer(pointerX, pointerY)) {
         hasDied=true;
     }else{
         isPaused=true;
     }
  }
```

Comment: check [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/Box2DTest.java) class